# Select from 2 mysql tables for php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site where my users will be displayed in a top-10 list.

Now we have added a form of respect, you can give a user a respect point through their profile-page.

But for the problem, in the toplist, I need to get USERNAME and LOOK from the table called Users. And I need to get the respect points from a table called user_stats.

How do I get this into the same thing?

```
mysql_query("SELECT `look`,`username` FROM `users` ORDER BY `Respect` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

So I need it like this or something:

```
mysql_query("SELECT `look`,`username` FROM `users` AND `RespectPoints` FROM `user_stats` ORDER BY `RespectPoints` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Anyone know how to do this, is it even possible?

Comment: please show your table structure...

Comment: that isn't how you query multiple tables using the `AND` logical operator. You need to research this. Edit: Seeing your comment below, this isn't a tutorial site.

Comment: which column is same in both tables?

Comment: look and username are from users and respectpoints are from table user_stats

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a join.

it will look something like this:

```
SELECT `look`,`username` FROM `users` u
join `userstats` s on s.userid=u.userid
DESC LIMIT 10
```

If you added your table structure and demo data I could write the exact query you need.

Comment: I have tried that, but didn't I need to select respectpoints from a table? and what is r.userid=u.userid? :P

Comment: typo after where, plus if you are using aliases, be consistent and use them  throughout